# Prove that $F$ can not be tangent to a surface.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suposse that $F=F(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is a vectorial field continuously differentiable and satisfies $div F =\partial_{x}  F_{1} + \partial_{y} F_{2} + \partial_{z} F_{3}>0$ in the interior of a domain $\Omega \subset R^{3}$, open and boundend, and it's frontier $\partial \Omega$ is at least class $C^{1}$ and orientable. Prove that $F$ can't be tangent to $\partial \Omega$ in all point of $\partial \Omega$.

I saw this problem in an admission test for a posgraduate program in mathematics and I don't know how to attack the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ is tangent to $\partial \Omega $ everywhere if and only if $F(x)\cdot \nu(x)=0$ for all $x\in \partial \Omega $, where $\nu$ is the exterior normal vector to $\partial \Omega $. Using divergence theorem yields $$\iint_{\partial \Omega }F\cdot \nu=\iiint_\Omega \text{div}(F)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d z>0.$$

Therefore, $F\cdot \nu=0$ doesn't hold everywhere on $\partial \Omega $.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the divergence theorem (or Gauss theorem).

$\int_{\partial \Omega} <F, \hat{n}> dS = \int_{\Omega} divF dx$

Here $<,>$ denote de internal product, and $\hat{n}$ is the outgoing unit vector on $\partial \Omega$.

You have $div F > 0 $ so the right integral is positive. Think, what happen with the left integral if $F$ is tangent to $\partial \Omega$ in all point of $\partial \Omega$.

Edit: You can use this theorem because you have the necessary hypotheses
.